# UIWebView best way to load an XML

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uiwebview

I want to display Xml file on UIWebView, what i am doing is this:

```
 [m_WebView loadData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:theURL] MIMEType:nil textEncodingName:nil baseURL:nil];
```

But this is not displaying it properly and i have no control over the color components of it, any suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use your own style sheet to enable control on component, else web view loads xml as its default format.

Check out following tutorial on css with UIWebView - http://mentormate.com/blog/iphone-uiwebview-class-local-css-javascript-resources/,  http://iphoneincubator.com/blog/windows-views/uiwebview-revisited

Comment: Tnx but what is happening is the UIWebView is not detecting the bold font and paragraphs and whole document is coming as plain text(non-bold and with different font), how to control this?

Comment: can you cross check your xml once, if that is in proper format?